# How to detect Windows 10 light/dark mode in Win32 application?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10, win32gui

A bit of context: [Sciter](https://sciter.com) (pure win32 application) is already capable to render UWP alike UIs:

in dark mode:
[image: in dark mode]

in light mode:
[image: in light mode]

Windows 10.1803 introduces Dark/Light switch in Settings applet [as seen here for example](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-enable-dark-mode-in-windows-10/).

Question: how do I determine current type of that "app mode" in Win32 application?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Well, it looks like this option is not exposed to regular Win32 applications directly, however it can be set / retrieved through the `AppsUseLightTheme` key at the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize` registry path.

Comment: Any way to subscribe to changes, short of polling this registry value every x seconds?

Comment: @SörenKuklau [RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winreg/nf-winreg-regnotifychangekeyvalue)

Comment: @SörenKuklau Better way is to listen for [`WM_WININICHANGE` broadcast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-wininichange) - `lParam == "ImmersiveColorSet"`.

Comment: Isn't [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange) a better message to listen to?

Comment: @dgellow Yes, but they're both `#define`d as the same value, so it doesn't matter at the compiler level.

Answer (score 10):

EDIT: Calling out that this works in all Win32 projects as long as you're building with c++17 enabled.

If you're using the latest SDK, this worked for me.

```cpp
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.h>

using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::ViewManagement;

if (RUNNING_ON_WINDOWS_10) {
  UISettings settings;
  auto background = settings.GetColorValue(UIColorType::Background);
  auto foreground = settings.GetColorValue(UIColorType::Foreground);
}
```

Comment: winrt is not win32 and the question was about specifically win32.

Comment: The reason I posted this was because it does indeed work with win32 applications on Windows 10. It does not require special permission or hacking into the registry.

Comment: According to MSDN:
"winrt::Windows::UI::ViewManagement - Provides support for handling and managing the various views associated with the active Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app." 

If it works in Win32 applications than by accident that can be fixed at any time.

Comment: @c-smile No accident, microsoft exposes all its UWP stuff to C++ apps via winrt. The [examples on the UISettings reference shows C++ code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings)

Comment: Except, types in the Windows Runtime, that are available to both UWP and Desktop applications have the [DualApiPartitionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.dualapipartitionattribute) assigned. The [UISettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings) class does not. Is that an oversight in the API? A documentation bug? Or an unsupported scenario, that occasionally appears to work?

Comment: How can I link to this? Which .lib should I add to the linker's input in Visual Studio?

Comment: @H.Al-Amri `WindowsApp.lib` contains everything you need.

Answer (score 9):

The [`Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts/) NuGet package gives .NET Framework 4.5+ and .NET Core 3.0+ applications access to Windows 10 WinRT APIs, including `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.Settings` mentioned in [the answer by *jarjar*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55670413/7872). With this package added to a .NET Core 3.0 console app that consists of this code:

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;

namespace WhatColourAmI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var settings = new UISettings();
            var foreground = settings.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Foreground);
            var background = settings.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Background);

            Console.WriteLine($"Foreground {foreground} Background {background}");
        }
    }
}
```

The output when the theme is set to *Dark* is:

> Foreground #FF**FFFFFF** Background #FF**000000**

When the theme is set to *Light* it's:

> Foreground #FF**000000** Background #FF**FFFFFF**

As this is exposed via a Microsoft provided package that states:

> This package includes all the supported Windows Runtime APIs up to Windows 10 version 1903

It's a pretty safe bet that it's intentional that this API is accessible!

**Note:** This isn't explicitly checking whether the theme is *Light* or *Dark* but checking for a pair of values that *suggest* that the theme in use is one of the two, so,.. the correctness of this method is mildly questionable but it's at least a "pure" C# way of achieving what's been outlined elsewhere with C++

Comment: is this included in .net framework? I dont want to install anything

Comment: According to the description of the NuGet package `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` .Net Framework 4.6+ is required not 4.5+.

Comment: @Robert, the latest version of the package available at the time of writing required 4.5+, it appears that this changed as of mid-May this year when 10.0.19041.1 was released

Answer (score 9):

To add to the solution suggested by @user7860670, i.e: checking the registry key `AppsUseLightTheme`, I think it is worth having some code example.

To read from the registry Win32 has [RegGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluew).

### C++

```cpp
bool is_light_theme() {
    // based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334674/how-to-detect-windows-10-light-dark-mode-in-win32-application

    // The value is expected to be a REG_DWORD, which is a signed 32-bit little-endian
    auto buffer = std::vector<char>(4);
    auto cbData = static_cast<DWORD>(buffer.size() * sizeof(char));
    auto res = RegGetValueW(
        HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Themes\\Personalize",
        L"AppsUseLightTheme",
        RRF_RT_REG_DWORD, // expected value type
        nullptr,
        buffer.data(),
        &cbData);

    if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Error: error_code=" + std::to_string(res));
    }

    // convert bytes written to our buffer to an int, assuming little-endian
    auto i = int(buffer[3] << 24 |
        buffer[2] << 16 |
        buffer[1] << 8 |
        buffer[0]);

    return i == 1;
}
```

### Rust

Using the [windows-rs](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs) projection crate:

```rust
pub fn is_light_theme() -> bool {
    // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51336913/709884
    let mut buffer: [u8; 4] = [0; 4];
    let mut cb_data: u32 = (buffer.len()).try_into().unwrap();
    let res = unsafe {
        RegGetValueW(
            HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
            r#"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize"#
                .to_wide()
                .as_pwstr(),
            "AppsUseLightTheme".to_wide().as_pwstr(),
            RRF_RT_REG_DWORD,
            std::ptr::null_mut(),
            buffer.as_mut_ptr() as _,
            &mut cb_data as *mut _,
        )
    };
    assert_eq!(
        res,
        ERROR_SUCCESS,
        format!("failed to read key from registry: err_code={}", res).as_str(),
    );

    // REG_DWORD is signed 32-bit, using little endian
    let light_mode = i32::from_le_bytes(buffer) == 1;
    light_mode
}

pub fn is_dark_theme() -> bool {
    !is_light_theme()
}

// convert &str to Win32 PWSTR
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct WideString(pub Vec<u16>);

pub trait ToWide {
    fn to_wide(&self) -> WideString;
}

impl ToWide for &str {
    fn to_wide(&self) -> WideString {
        let mut result: Vec<u16> = self.encode_utf16().collect();
        result.push(0);
        WideString(result)
    }
}

impl ToWide for String {
    fn to_wide(&self) -> WideString {
        let mut result: Vec<u16> = self.encode_utf16().collect();
        result.push(0);
        WideString(result)
    }
}

impl WideString {
    pub fn as_pwstr(&self) -> PWSTR {
        PWSTR(self.0.as_ptr() as *mut _)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a C# solution for the answer of @user7860670

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

try
{
    int res = (int)Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Themes\\Personalize", "AppsUseLightTheme", -1);
}
catch 
{
 //Exception Handling     
}
```

res contains the value for the default theme on windows

0 : dark theme

1 : light theme

-1 : AppsUseLightTheme could not be found