# How to build a dark UI application in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to build in Visual Studio 2019 a WindowsForms application that will honor Windows 10 Settings> Personalization> Colors> Choose your color> Dark?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect Windows 10 light/dark mode in Win32 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334674/how-to-detect-windows-10-light-dark-mode-in-win32-application)

Comment: No magic there for WinForms apps. Build your app with different themes and switch by detecting what Windows 10 color mode is.