# RegGetValueW(), how to do it right

Tags: windows, rust, windows-rs

I'm creating a windows app that can change system color.

I saw this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70753913/16371490), where we are accessing and reading from registry with `RegGetValueW()`. Then I copied and changed it a little with the help of compiler:

```rust
use windows::{Win32::System::Registry::RegGetValueW, core::PWSTR};
use winreg::enums::*;

pub fn is_light_theme() -> bool {
    // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51336913/709884
    let mut buffer: [u8; 4] = [0; 4];
    let mut cb_data: u32 = (buffer.len()).try_into().unwrap();
    let res = unsafe {
        RegGetValueW(
            HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
            w!(r#"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize"#),
            w!("AppsUseLightTheme"),
            RRF_RT_REG_DWORD,
            Some(std::ptr::null_mut()),
            Some(buffer.as_mut_ptr() as _),
            Some(&mut cb_data as *mut u32),
        )
    };
    assert_eq!(
        res,
        ERROR_SUCCESS,
        format!("failed to read key from registry: err_code= {}", res).as_str(),
    );

    // REG_DWORD is signed 32-bit, using little endian
    let light_mode = i32::from_le_bytes(buffer) == 1;
    light_mode
}

pub fn is_dark_theme() -> bool {
    !is_light_theme()
}

// convert &str to Win32 PWSTR
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct WideString(pub Vec<u16>);

pub trait ToWide {
    fn to_wide(&self) -> WideString;
}

impl ToWide for &str {
    fn to_wide(&self) -> WideString {
        let mut result: Vec<u16> = self.encode_utf16().collect();
        result.push(0);
        WideString(result)
    }
}

impl ToWide for String {
    fn to_wide(&self) -> WideString {
        let mut result: Vec<u16> = self.encode_utf16().collect();
        result.push(0);
        WideString(result)
    }
}

impl WideString {
    pub fn as_pwstr(&self) -> PWSTR {
        PWSTR(self.0.as_ptr() as *mut _)
    }
}
```

From where is it getting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, `RRF_RT_REG_DWORD`, `ERROR_SUCCESS`?

I'm getting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` with help of `winreg` crate, but I assume you can get `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, `RRF_RT_REG_DWORD` from `windows-rs` directly, couldn't find this info.

I know that this code will not change system colors, reading theme value from registry is the closest target for me right now.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you answered both of my questions. I will keep in mind rule "1 question post - 1 question"

Comment: @cafce25 Yes, I disagree. The second question is not a duplicate of your proposed dupe (you'll have time to verify this once my proposed answer is up). And the link you provided from your *"simple search"* leads to the wrong documentation. So may there's more to this than you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question revolves around discoverability. The current situation isn't great and you will have to look up information in two places:

1. The [crate documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/index.html), and
2. The [feature index](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-rs/features/#/master).

The first resource answers the question of where to find any given symbol. Both `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `RRF_RT_REG_DWORD` are exported from the `windows::Win32::System::Registry` module. (I'd link to the documentation, but those links may no longer be correct when the next version is published<sup>1</sup>.)

`ERROR_SUCCESS` is exported from the `windows::Win32::Foundation` module, a foundational module used across the entire API.

Once you know which modules to `use` you have to make sure to enable the respective features. That's what the second resource is for. The only feature you need here is `"Win32_System_Registry"`; the `windows::Win32::Foundation` module is no longer feature-gated.

The second question is concerned with string representations. Rust's internal string representation is unfortunately alien to Windows' and work is required to bridge the impedance mismatch. The [`windows`](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate provides basic translation primitives. For string literals, you can use the [`w!`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/macro.w.html) macro that re-encodes the source string as UTF-16, appends a NUL character and returns a `PCWSTR` ready for use.

The following compiles and runs as expected:

*main.rs*

```rust
use windows::{
    core::w,
    Win32::{Foundation::*, System::Registry::*},
};

pub fn is_light_theme() -> bool {
    // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51336913/709884
    let mut buffer: [u8; 4] = [0; 4];
    let mut cb_data: u32 = (buffer.len()).try_into().unwrap();
    let res = unsafe {
        RegGetValueW(
            HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
            w!(r#"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize"#),
            w!("AppsUseLightTheme"),
            RRF_RT_REG_DWORD,
            Some(std::ptr::null_mut()),
            Some(buffer.as_mut_ptr() as _),
            Some(&mut cb_data as *mut u32),
        )
    };
    assert_eq!(res, ERROR_SUCCESS);

    // REG_DWORD is signed 32-bit, using little endian
    let light_mode = i32::from_le_bytes(buffer) == 1;
    light_mode
}

fn main() {
    let light_theme = is_light_theme();
    println!("Light theme: {light_theme:?}");
}
```

*Cargo.toml*

```ini
[package]
name = "is_light_theme"
version = "0.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.54.0"
features = ["Win32_System_Registry"]
```

There's no need to use the [`winreg`](https://crates.io/crates/winreg) crate.

As an alternative, you could use the [`windows-registry`](https://crates.io/crates/windows-registry) instead. It is part of the same repository as the `windows` crate. This vastly cuts down on the amount of code you need to write.

*main.rs*

```rust
use windows_registry::*;

pub fn is_light_theme() -> bool {
    let val = CURRENT_USER
        .open(r#"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize"#)
        .expect("Failed to get registry key")
        .get_u32("AppsUseLightTheme")
        .expect("Failed to get registry value");
    val != 0
}

fn main() {
    let light_theme = is_light_theme();
    println!("Light theme: {light_theme:?}");
}
```

*Cargo.toml*

```ini
[package]
name = "is_light_theme"
version = "0.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
windows-registry = { version = "0.1.0" }
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *Unfortunately, `docs.rs` is [unable](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/2750) to handle the `windows` crate, and the crate maintainers are forced to entertain a custom hosting solution with a fire-and-forget data retention policy.*

Comment: [And here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fmicrosoft.github.io%2Fwindows-docs-rs%2F+HKEY_CURRENT_USER+&t=ffab&ia=web) where you'll find [this](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Registry/constant.HKEY_CURRENT_USER.html) just as in your answer but as a link.

Comment: @cafce25 That's a link to a search engine query, that doesn't even list the correct answer as the first result.

Comment: "Search, and research" – [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), I think that involves clicking more than the first link, or y'know maybe cliking the link that contains the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` in it's title……… Also the point was that a simple search does find it, within the first page of results I think does fall within simple search.

Comment: Hence the link to a search that finds it...

Comment: The question doesn't contain the `PCWSTR` problem any longer so explaining that is just noise.

Comment: @cafce25 This is a kind reminder to stop vandalizing my answer. It is worded this way for a reason. Ripping out a crucial part that explains a substantial change to the code is *harmful*. I will roll the edit back one more time, and take it to moderation if you continue this rollback-war.

Comment: "The second question" – Which second question?